# Holder continuous but not Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Is there a function that is Holder continuous but not Lipschitz continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition),

The function $f(x) = x^\beta$ (with $\beta \le 1$) defined on $[0, 1]$ serves as a prototypical example of a function that is $C^{0,\alpha}$ Hölder continuous for $0 < \alpha \le \beta$, but not for $\alpha>\beta$. In particular, if we choose $\beta<1$, it's not Lipschitz.

Do you know how to check this statement?

Comment: I know how to check the Hölder continuity where it is Hölder, but I don't know how to show it's not Lipschitz.